# How to deny all ports to localhost, from localhost, except one, using iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, vagrant

I have an issue with iptables where I'm unable to connect to localhost from localhost. Basically, I want all incoming packets, except those with a destination for SSH and port 9000 to be dropped. Packets with a destination for localhost:9000 must have a source port equal to port 8000.

Simple enough?

Why doesn't this work with the following rules? Note that this is inside a Vagrant instance (hashicorp/precise64).

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:8000 dpt:9000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh state ESTABLISHED
```

I attempt this with the following command:

```
# nc -p 8000 localhost 9000
```

-p sets the source port.

Which does nothing.

I've also tried to have no source port requirement for 8000, and only matching on the destination port, same result.

I add the rules like this:

Match both dpt and spt:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 8000 --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
```

Match only dpt:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
```

As stated above, neither works.

Changing the policy on INPUT to ACCEPT makes it work, but why doesn't it work with DROP as the default policy when I have this specific rule to allow it?

Not that I think it matters, but the use case here is for port knocking. I'm aware I have to use /etc/knockd.conf to actually open and close the ports -- so far I'm only debugging. If I can't get it working from the command line manually, it will never work with knockd.

As requested, here is more verbose information:

```
# iptables -nvL --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 17 packets, 1164 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    42847 1832K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
2        3   180 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:8000 dpt:9000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 21 packets, 1420 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    38138 3415K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:22 state ESTABLISHED


# iptables -t nat -nvL --line-numbers 
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: You don't need the OUTPUT rule if you've got policy ACCEPT. The config seems fine, but please add the output of `iptables -nvL --line-numbers` and `iptables -t nat -nvL --line-numbers`

Comment: @Lenniey thanks, I've provided the requested outputs in my edited post. I realize the OUTPUT rule isn't needed, it is a leftover from when the policy was DROP. However, removing the rule as it is now from OUTPUT doens't change anything (I've tried).

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here:

https://superuser.com/questions/808496/difference-between-iptables-default-policy-to-drop-and-inserting-a-seperate-po

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```